# ios Swift 3 using Property Observer update Image from UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Hi I'm using IOS swift 3 to let user pick images from library or album.
I have an UIImage variable.
How can we use property Observer to update the UIImage when user finished pick an Image

Some thing like

```
var image: UIImage = {
    didSet....
 }
```

Currently I'm doing this

```
func show(image: UIImage) {
   imageView.image = image
   imageView.isHidden = false
   imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 260, height: 260)
       addPhotoLabel.isHidden = true
}


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

   image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
   if let theImage = image {
     show(image: theImage)
   }
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thinking of using property Observer to improve the approach.
Any help is much appreciate.
Thanks!

Comment: Why? You don't even need your `image` property. All you are doing is setting the image to the `imageView`.

Comment: I'm saying you can get rid of your `image` property. You don't need it.

Comment: How to achieve that? the image is the IBOutlet. @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

Comment: The `imageView` property is an outlet. I'm saying you don't need the `image` property.

Comment: Yes I'm thingking of using Property Observer.  Some thing like imageView { didSet...} to auto update imageView when user pick an image from library or take a picture

Comment: Again, why? There's no point. The code you have is fine.

Comment: Hi It's for a better refactor approach. We can omit the show(image: UIImage) function! and have an auto update property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to update the image view any time the `image` property is set, then simply put all of the code in your `show` method in the `didSet` block for the `image` property.

```
var image: UIImage = {
    didSet {
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.isHidden = false
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 260, height: 260)
        addPhotoLabel.isHidden = true
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let theImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        image = theImage
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, That's a good approach. No need to call extra function when we want to update the imageView